# Which method is faster? back_inserter or resize

Tags: c++, stl

I want to copy from vector v1 of type uint into v2 of type uint.

V1 has about 750,000 elements.

Option 1:

```
std::copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::back_inserter(v2));
```

or

Option 2:

```
v2.resize(v1.size());
std::copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(),v2.begin());
```

Which option would be faster? We do not use c++11.

Thank you!

Comment: If you add a `v2.reserve(v1.size())` to Option 1, I think they'd be pretty close.

Comment: A reliable answer: benchmark it yourself.

Comment: Is v1 of type `float` or uint?  You disagree with yourself in the first two paragraphs.

Comment: Another contender is using SSE, but maybe the compiler is smart enough to do use these instructions, etc. The only way to know is to benchmark. And that means benchmark *your application* (and figure out if this is a bottleneck), not some simple test code.

Comment: @Yakk, V1 is of type uint. Fixed it.

Comment: So, does the second vector have to be `double`, or can it be layout-compatible with a `double`?  (ie, match its binary representation, but not be the type `double`)  Because a struct that doesn't zero its contained `double` makes the resize case faster, and would enable a hand-optimized SSE loop.

Answer (score 6):

You are probably trying too hard.  :-)

```
v2.assign(v1.begin(), v1.end());
```

will work fine, and take care of the resize/reserve as needed.

Comment: can we use the swap method may be faster if we dont need the content of vector v1 ? v2.swap(v1); ? because swap is in constant time: cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/swap

Comment: @Hocine - No, the vectors contain integer and floating point, so they cannot be swapped. The values have to be copied (and converted during the copy).

Comment: @BoPersson, complexity of vector::assign is linear which is what I am trying to avoid. std::copy does bulk transfer if the value type is TriviallyCopiable. I am not sure if the uint to double qualifies as TriviallyCopiable.

Comment: @sgowd  - You have two different types, so they *have to* be converted while copying. `std::copy` cannot get around that.

Comment: @sgowd You are operating on n elements.  This is inherently linear.  Even bulk copies are still linear.  No, memmov or memcpy won't be used for uint to double.

Comment: @BoPersson, and Yakk I modified my code so that now even the To type is also a uint. What do you recommend now?

Comment: Not that it matters much here, but you really shouldn't rewrite the question after it is answered. That often confuses other people reading this later. Anyway, if you want to keep the original you *have* to copy all elements. And using `std::copy` is ok for that. If `memcpy` would be an optimization for some data types, you can expect `std::copy` to use that internally. Your compiler's std library is written by guys who aren't stupid, and known to benchmark their code! Otherwise, if you don't need the original data, moving or swapping will most often be faster.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very late reply, but a few years back I did some experiments and did some measurements. They are available at my blog [Copying memory from C to C++ using std::vector](http://thewayofc.blogspot.se/2014/05/copying-memory-from-c-to-c-using.html). It lists a few other options as well and the results might be interesting for others.